# Can the domain control server and team foundation server been installed on the same machine?

Tags: dns

I have installed team foundation server adopt the workgroup style, and I find the user manage is difficult, so I want to adpot domain. Can the domain control server and team foundation server been installed on the same machine? Is there need some virtual technology? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the domain controller can be on the same machine, though it is not recommended. You do not need any virtual machines for this.  Actually putting a domain controller on a virtual machine will make things more complex for you so if you are just making a domain for the first time I would avoid using a virtual machine to host it.

Comment: Thank you! I did it. I updated my server and make it been a domain controler, but I found that team foundation server cannot work normally. I cannot access the web http://servername:8080/tfs/web. Why is this so? How could I do it?